# Summing the digits of a sum of digits of a sum

Tags: python, beginner, iteration

I'm a beginner in Python, and computer languages in general, and I'm totally stumped on how to format this iteration into a function. The iteration takes the sum of someone's birth year, month, and day and adds it together to create a sum of those numbers, and then the second iteration takes the first sum and adds those numbers together to create a final sum.

I have the users input their birthyear, month, and day (all converted to int) and this is the first sum (Example: A bday of 01/01/1997= 1999):

```
first_sum=b_yr + b_dy + b_mo
```

Then the first iteration takes the sum and adds the numbers together (Example: 1999 = 1+9+9+9 = 28):

```
z = first_sum
zstr1=str(z)
accum1=0
for x in zstr1:
    accum1 += int(x)
(accum1)
```

Then the second iteration takes the first sum and adds those numbers again to create the final sum (Example: 28 = 2+8 = 10):

```
str2=str(accum1)
accum2=0
for cnt2 in str2:
    accum2 += int(cnt2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite your code being cumbersome, I would like to point out that you did well by writing `for x in zstr1`, iterating over the characters of the string.  Python beginners often try to iterate over character indexes instead, resulting in unnatural Python code.

---

I would decompose the problem differently than @jonrsharpe.  `sum_digits(n)` is a generally useful operation to define as a function.

```
def sum_digits(n):
    return sum(int(char) for char in str(n))

sum_digits(sum_digits(b_yr + b_mo + b_dy))
```

---

Actually, it's not necessary to conflate the summing and the digit breakdown.

```
def digits(n):
    return [int(char) for char in str(n)]

sum(digits(sum(digits(b_yr + b_mo + b_dy))))
```

The last line reads just like the problem description: "sum of the digits of the sum of the digits of the year, month, and day".

---

Here's another implementation of `digits(n)`, using a generator.  This avoids stringification.

```
def digits(n):
    """Produce the base-10 digits of n from least to most significant."""
    while n:
        yield n % 10
        n /= 10
```

Comment: `sum_digits` could be `sum(map(int, str(n)))` if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes on your code:

- You should be more consistent with whitespace. [The style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests a space each side of `=` in assignments - you use this once, but elsewhere leave them out.
- Variable names could be a bit more useful/consistent - for example, you have `z` (what does that mean?) and `zstr1` but `str2` (why not `str1` and `str2`, or `zstr1` and `zstr2`?) A good choice of name can make the code much easier to understand.
- In fact, `z` is redundant; you can replace `z = first_sum` and `zstr1=str(z)` with `zstr1 = str(first_sum)`.

---

Your approach is fine as far as it goes, but here is a neater implementation:

```
def process(b_yr, b_dy, b_mo):
    total = b_yr + b_dy + b_mo
    for _ in range(2):
        total = sum([int(char) for char in str(total)])
    return total
```

Note that:

1. **You need to sum over the digits of a number** - it uses a [*"list comprehension"*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to apply the same process to each character/digit in the number, and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to add up the total.
2. **You need to repeat this process twice** - it uses a `for` loop to repeat the process, rather than just writing it out again; this reduces duplication and makes it much easier to repeat the process a different number of times.

As a more shorter and more *"functional programming"*, but perhaps less readable, alternative for step 1. you can replace the list comprehension with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
total = sum(map(int, str(total)))
```